# Attach EBS Volume to Master node of an EMR Cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform

We have a recent requirement of deploying an EMR cluster with the master node attached with an EBS volume (Say 250G).
I have checked the documentation of terraform and got the code for below resources:

- EMR cluster
- EBS volume
- Attaching an EBS volume.

How can we achieve all three in single deployment ?
The confusion came when I found that we need the instance id of the master node (any EC2 instance ) basically to attach an EBS volume to it and I am not sure of any way to find the instance id of a node which you are trying to deploy at the same time.

Can some one please help on this, as this will be really useful for us.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can boot strap an Emr cluster with required EBS volumes attached.
[image]

You can see it in the advanced options in the create cluster Console. So there is a posibility in the cluster spin-up syntax to attach the EBS volumes. When the cluster is boot strapped.

the following shows you can bootstrap it please see in the following link
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-emr-update-support-for-ebs-volumes-and-m4-c4-instance-types/

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-emr-cluster-jobflowinstancesconfig-instancegroupconfig.html